# Using mp4 files/jpeg sequences/gif animations in android?Which is better and How to efficiently use these?

Tags: android, null, gif, mp4, movie

I have been posting quite some questions recently without getting a response. Hope this one gets.

Iv decided to go with mp4 as its compression is much better than gif sequences. Trying movie.decodestream(*InputStream*) helps to get the stream. But when movie.duration() is aquired, a null pointer exception is thrown. Going around the web, I found that duration works if the movies are frame by frame(with durations for each). 
So, is the mp4 sequence a bad way to read the stream and get the duration?
Is there any way to convert the mp4 into a "frame by frame" sequence?

What is required is an easy way to play some 30 frame animations on screen. 
The problems of each solution Iv found are: Jpeg sequences are pretty much memory consuming, Gif sequences when used have jagged edges and bigger file sizes and mp4 sequences cannot be acquired for frame by frame playback.
- Since the animations have a dimension of 800*600, I guess Jpeg sequences are out of the question, or please do tell if there are any good options for this.
- Presently Im using gif sequences,with half the dimension. The edges are jagged and are displayed very bad in different devices.
-Mp4 Sequences are just too good. But I need the control over the frames so that I can play it forward and reverse, and display the first and last frames at the resting stage of the animation(the animations are triggered on touch).

Comment: Try to explain us what you want to achieve and what you already tried! Perhaps we are than able to give you hints. I still didn't even nearly understand what you are trying. You want to use an H264 video to efficiently store single pictures? You now want to decode the h264 and get the frames in your Java code?

Why not use jpg if gif doesn't compresss well enough?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wanted to play some animations which I rendered as a *.mp4(h264) file. I could render this as jpeg images as you suggested(big help there, and part of my question answered), but could you suggest some pointers on how to decode jpeg sequences(and on how to specify how long a frame of the animation should be displayed). Secondly, if there is a method to directly play the mp4 file,frame by frame, please do share. Ultimately what I want is good quality and compression. Which would you suggest for the same? The animations are 800*600 and not more than 2 seconds long.

Comment: Also, I have used movie.duration() and movie.setTime() so that I can determine the duration of the movie and what frame comes at a particular time. Can the same be done for jpeg sequence/mp4?